# "Voivode" word usage in modern English

Tags: word-usage

"Voivode" - is this word used commonly in English? Also others like 'voivodeship' (e.g. for a road)?

Which I personally, as a native Polish speaker, would like to use in the modern context as a reference to provincial roads.

Comment: The word is fairly obscure, but is found in a number of English dictionaries...

Comment: I'm aware of it as the title of some sort of official, but wouldn't understand the connection with roads.

Comment: While the term has nothing to do with "roads" it has much to do with "provinces". These voivodes were governors over provinces in medieval times. But I would call "voivodeship" a [barbarism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barbarism_(linguistics)).

Comment: You might use it in English but only in the context of Poland or other areas where the word is used in the native language, similar to how one might use 'oblast' in English but only for Russian areas.

Comment: *"I would like to use in the modern context as a reference to provincial roads."* - A reference to provincial roads where? In Slavic countries, okay. In Britain or the USA? Absolutely not. Please say how and where you want to use it.

Comment: As I said `as a native Polish speaker` so I want to use this in Poland. But I also want to know how to say the same thoughts in international company.

Comment: 1) what exactly does it mean? You seem to think it refers to a road or a province, but English dictionaries say (the English) word is about a person (a provincial governor). 2)  _Why_ do you want to use this word -in English-? What's the point since English speakers most likely won't understand. Is it because you'll be speaking English -to other Poles-? YOu need to edit your question to clarify all these points.

Comment: in short, ...... I would like to describe the fact that the voivode, by virtue of the office, is responsible for the condition of the voivodeship roads. As for now when I would like to describe this to @Mitch I would use `Provincial governor, by virtue of the office, is responsible for the condition of the provincial roads.` Would this be good translation if I as a inhabitant of Poland, would like to say it to you ?

Comment: That sentence is very understandable to me, that is, it sounds like a good translation. If you used 'voivodeship' or 'voivode' instead, I would have had no idea (before today). But I am no Poland scholar - use of 'voivode' may well be the way to speak about Poland in English. But as the official answers all seem to corroborate, 'voivoide' is not common in English.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Collins and Merriam-Webster agree that the "common" spelling is *[vaivode](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/vaivode)*, but that is to overstate: neither *voivode* nor *vaivode* are common in English, and most English-speakers will not be familiar with it unless they have greater than average knowledge about the history or geography of Central and Eastern Europe.

There are only two results for *voivode* in the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/), both from the same website about a television episode featuring Dracula, and none for *vaivode*. There is only one result for *voivode* in the slightly older British National Corpus, about Janos Hunyadi (coincidentally about Transylvania, if not Dracula).

I was not myself familiar with *voivode*, although I was aware of *voivodeship* being the word for a subdivision of Poland. As with terms like *prefectures* or *Länder* it may be used if the reader is expected to be familiar with the term, but for broader audiences will be translated as *province*, *region*, *state*, or so on as may be conventional.

Comment: I’ve never heard of it at all.  I actually would have guessed it was a French word I’d never heard of.

Comment: @Jim: Do you speak French? I can see why you thought that, actually. The word's ending "-de" is quite common in French.

Comment: @fev - I took it in school for 5 years and was in an exchange program back in 1980 but it’s basically gone unused since then. So I’m no longer conversant. I can still tell you when the English subtitles are wrong though :-)

Comment: @choster you said that `for broader audiences will be translated as province, region, state, or so on as may be conventional` is that mean that I should use `inter regional roads`but I do not mean about `expressway` or `highway` but a type of road that is maintained by the regional authority but not the municipal authority.

Comment: @MichałLipok Terminology for roads varies considerably by locale, but *highway* does not necessarily mean *expressway*, and I would suggest *provincial highway* for a road that is maintained by the voivodeship regardless of its size. *Provincial road* would also be understood. In the U.S. it might be called a *[state highway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_highway)*, *state route*, or *state road* by different people, and there are also *county roads* or *county routes* at the level below that.

Comment: `county roads or county routes at the level below that` how they differ, what you mean by `level below`

Comment: @MichałLipok - it means public roads can be maintained at the federal level, state level, county level, city level, subdivision/housing-development level

Answer (score 2):

I was expecting to see zero results but there are some for **voivode**:

[lengusa](https://lengusa.com/search/Voivode)

And only one for **vaivode**:

[lengusa](https://lengusa.com/search/vaivode)

All of them are from *Encyclopedia Britannica* and seem to related to Balkans or Romania. Example:

> When the Turks decisively defeated Hungary at the Battle of Mohács (1526), Transylvania effectively became independent. Its voivode John (János Zápolya), who was elected king of Hungary (November 1526), engaged Transylvania in a 12-year war against Ferdinand I, the Habsburg claimant to the Hungarian throne. Afterward Hungary was divided between the Habsburgs and the Turks, and Transylvania was transformed into an autonomous principality that was subject to Turkish suzerainty (1566).
> -- Encyclopedia Britannica

Answer (score 1):

You will find the word used in the trilogy *With Fire and Sword* by the Polish author Henryk Sienkowitz. This is the only place I ever met the word. It is a translation that retains the original form rather than using English alternatives. Therefore I cannot recommend using it in contemporary English without explanation.

> [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/With_Fire_and_Sword)

> [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topor%C3%B3w,_%C5%9Awi%C4%99tokrzyskie_Voivodeship)

Here it refers to an administrative area or province, the Voivodeship, whose leader is the Voivode.

It comes from Slavonic roots such as Russian Voina, war, and Vodit’, to lead. Hence the Voivode is the military, or partly military, leader of the province or voivodeship.